# FUTURE PERFECT and HOPE

Tags: meaning, perfect-constructions, connotations, future

If the future perfect is used to describe an expected or planned event before a time of reference, then how is it possible for us to use the word 'hope'? I need an explanation of the nuance here.

I'll have seen more of the world three years from now.

I hope I'll have seen more of the world three years from now.

Comment: You hope that you **will see** more of the world during the next three years - so, at a point three years in the future, those travels will be in the past. You **will have seen** more.

Comment: Does 'hope' mean something like "it is my desired goal" in this instance?

Comment: Yes, hope is expressing a wish or intention in your example. Although it can be used in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, "I hope I'll have seen more of the world three years from now," you're using the future perfect to express a wish about a future state. You're hoping that by a specific time (three years from now), you will have the completed action of seeing more of the world. There's a desire present ("hope"), but there's also uncertainty about whether it will actually happen.

---

You could also express this using the simple future:

"I hope I will see more of the world in the next three years."

This  doesn't  emphasize completion as strongly as the future perfect, but it still conveys the hope for future travel.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope my sprained ankle will have healed long before the championship game.

My hope now, as I speak, is that my sprained ankle will be *fully* healed (**will have healed**) well in advance of the championship game.

In your example, your hope is that you will have been to other countries three years from now; that  three years from now, those visits will be in your past: they will be a part of your life experience.